# Is there any way of initializing variables and let constants in an API response model without defining their type?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

While creating a response model for an API when I initialize the variables and constants with the names that I am going to get from the API response I have to declare their types, i.e. `String`, `Bool`, `Int`.

My question is, is there any way that while initializing all this is there a way that I don't have to define the type of the variables or constants?

Because sometimes if I have declared a variable as `String` and in the response JSON the value of that key is `Int` the JSON decoder doesn't decode it and fails with an error.

So is there a library or something else I can use that will help me with this?

I have tried JSON decoder and mapper but they didn't or maybe I didn't do it right

Comment: Swift is a strongly typed language. You can declare a property as `Any` but that is going to be a pain to deal with. You could use a custom decoder that converts the value from the JSON to a consistent type, but really the API should be fixed to be consistent

Comment: An API that can return different types for a value is, in my opinion, poorly designed. If you have access to the API, my suggestion would be to fix the API instead.

Comment: thanks both of you for the answers. you guys are right API should be fixed but i just wanted to learn a way of handling this problem and i just found out a way of doing this through a duplicate question but thank you for helping :D